# AngularJS- setting up Protractor to test front-end user interaction

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, angular, virtualmachine

I am working on an AngularJS app, and am looking to add some automated testing to the development life cycle of the project.

After doing a bit of research, and asking on here about what frameworks would be best to use to enable the testing functionality that I require, I have decided to use Protractor as the testing framework for my app.

I am following the [tutorial](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) to try and get Protractor up and running with my application (i.e. with my existing app, not the Super Calculator application that the tutorial references), but am encountering a problem:

The way my development environment is set up, is that I am doing all of the development of the AngularJS app on my local Windows machine, and using a Unix VM (running CentOS) to serve my app's front-end using `grunt`.

I have run through the setup steps in the tutorial, and have all of that set up correctly. However, on Step 0, after creating the `spec.js` & `conf.js` files as instructed, when I then run:

```
protractor conf.js
```

in the command line, I get the following output:

> [16:18:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>
> [16:18:39] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>
> [16:18:40] E/launcher - Error code: 135
>
> [16:18:40] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
>
> [16:18:40] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
>       at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\Elgan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:238:15)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>
> From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.createSession (C:\Users...\webdriver.js:777:24)
>       at Function.createSession (C:\Users...\chrome.js:709:29)
>       at createDriver (C:\Users...\index.js:167:33)
>       at Builder.build (C:\Users...\index.js:623:16)
>       at Hosted.getNewDriver (C:\Users...\driverProvider.ts:60:29)
>       at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users...\runner.ts:225:39)
>       at q.then.then (C:\Users...\runner.ts:391:27)
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users...\q.js:834:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users...\q.js:863:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users...\q.js:796:13)
>
> [16:18:40] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135

My guess is that this is happening because of the address/ port I'm using when running it (i.e. the address/ port used on the VM)?

Would that be the case? If so, what IP address/ port should I be using? The port that I have Karma set up on is: 9876- should I be using this port, rather than the one from the tutorial (4444)? Or if not, how can I resolve this issue?

**Edit**

When running `webdriver-manager start`, the console shows the following output:

> [16:59:26] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users...\chromedriver_2.32.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users...\geckodriver-v0.19.0.exe -jar C:\Users...\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port 4444
>
> [16:59:26] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 11464
>   'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   [16:59:27] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default config suggested in the tutorial, Protractor expects a selenium server at the `127.0.0.1:4444` address. And, I suspect, you have not started a selenium server.

So, one way to approach it would be to use `webdriver-manager` package to start a local selenium server as suggested in the [Setup section of the tutorial](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial#setup):

```
webdriver-manager start
```

And leave it open. Then, run `protractor` from a different command-line.

Another option would be to directly interact with the browser without a selenium server. Currently you can only do that with Chrome and Firefox only. Set the [`directConnect` to `true` in your config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L187) and remove the `seleniumAddress` configuration parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run `webdriver-manager start`, I get some output that seems to be complaining that `'java' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`...? I'll update my OP to show the full message now.

Comment: @someone2088 I guess this is your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command. Give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So I've configured my environment variables, but now when I run `webdriver-manager start` again, I get quite a lot of error output in the console, the last four lines of which are: `Unrecognized option: -port`, `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`, `Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.` & `I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1`... The port being used is 4444 & the seleniumProcess.pid is 5507. Any suggestions as to why I'm getting this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Ah, it seems that error was because I had forgotten to become `root` before running the command